# Is there any way that I can store Application.Current.Properties in a database so I could share these among multiple devices?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application tries to share data among devices by storing the settings in a database. Are there any plug ins or examples of where the data that is stored in Application.Current.Properties can be persisted to a database that would allow this?

Comment: This is OS dependent, which OS(s) are you targeting?

Comment: to share data among devices you need to create an api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you are trying to access one application's saved properties from another application. For security reasons, this isn't allowed, especially with the `Application.Current.Properties` object.

Although I haven't tried this, you could use the [NuGet SQLite Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) to save the database to the External Storage, then have apps access that same location. Alternatively, save the properties to a (encoded/encrypted?) text file in the External Storage, then have the other apps access that same text file(s). Be sure there are no sensitive information!